# Constructing estimated ARMA series

Tags: arma

I have a time sequence $y_t$ and I want to estimte it via an ARMA(2,2) model, i. e.

$$y_t = \phi_1y_{t-1}+\phi_2y_{t-2}+\theta_1 \epsilon_{t-1}+\theta_1 \epsilon_{t-2}+\epsilon_t $$

I was able to estimate the coefficients using an MLE on a Kalman Filter of $y_t$. $$[\phi_1,\phi_2,\theta_1,\theta_2]=[.72,.23,.46,.35]$$

My question is now that I have the coefficients, how do I construct $\hat{y_t}$ ?

$y_{t-1}, y_{t-2}$ are lags but how do I get the residuals to construct the series? Do I regress $y_t$ on  $y_{t-1}, y_{t-2}$ and the residuals give me $\epsilon_{t},\epsilon_{t-1},\epsilon_{t-2}$ which then I multiply by the estimated coefficients to construct the series? I know the software packages can do it for you but I simply wan to know the process of how to build out the estimated series after the coefficients have been estimated. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\hat{y}_t$? How do you want to use it? For example, in the Kalman filter setting, typically the "residuals" that we use for model diagnostics are the one-step-ahead forecast errors on $y_{t+1}$, which would mean that a natural meaning to give to $\hat{y}_t$ is the one-step-ahead forecast. Other meanings would be the expected value of $y_t$ given past and current observations, or all observations (Kalman smoother).

Comment: Thank you Chris, I see. The way I constructed the Kalman filter is I first guessed the coefficients, then generated 1-step forcasts using those coefficient and constructed a Likelihood function which then I maximized it. So to get the estimated y hat, I should run this process over again but then using the maximized coefficient values from the MLE which will generate the optimal 1-step ahead forcasts. Am i understanding this correctly?

Comment: Jessica, you need to add @ before the user name, otherwise the user is not notified of your comment. Also, please do not post [the same question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268377/predicted-values-of-an-arma) twice (unless the other question is sufficiently different from this one). Cc @ChrisHaug

Comment: Yes, that's correct, run the Kalman filter with your MLE parameters. A typical Kalman filter implementation will compute and output the state estimate both given only past information (i.e. the one-step-ahead state forecast) and given past and current information (the "filtered" state estimate). If you apply the observation matrix to either of these you will get some version of $\hat{y}_t$. Which one you want depends on what you want to use it for, as I said above.